# OpenCL, how do I generalize code for large computations?

Tags: opencl

I am confused about how OpenCL divides a massive computation task. I am unsure about how to ask the questions correctly, so please let me start with how I think OpenCL works, and then I will ask a specific question based on the example. Here's how I think it works:

- load in the kernel
- set the arguments
- choose the number of work items   **<- my question will be about this step**
- and then run the kernel.

---

Suppose I want to use a kernel (whatever it is) to solve a given number of problems. I manually set `local_item_size`, and then set `global_item_size` so that it is one multiple of `local_item_size` larger than `number of problems`. Like this:

```
// Set work item population 
local_item_size = 8;
global_item_size = (number_of_problems / local_item_size + 1) * local_item_size;

// Run
clEnqueueNDRangeKernel(queue, kernel, 1, NULL, &global_item_size, &local_item_size, 0, NULL, NULL);
```

So, if there are `number_of_problems = 25` then `global_item_size = 32`. This is because the smallest multiple of `8` that is greater than `25` is `32`. Okay, simple enough, the kernel runs and we ignore the results of some items, job done.

---

Now let's suppose I want my to do the same, but for massive numbers of work items. As an example, say I want to run the kernel for every combination of indices in some large array:

```
number_of_problems = getCombinations(input);

// Set work item population 
local_item_size = _____;
global_item_size = (number_of_problems / local_item_size + 1) * local_item_size;
```

If `input` is large, the `number_of_problems` will be very large - you get the idea I think. I want to understand **how** to go about choosing `local_item_size` wisely.

---

Finally, my two-part question:

1) When using a GPU, does OpenCL:

- a) run some set of work-groups, then another set, and so on until all work items have finished, or
- b) simply try to run all of the work-groups at once?

If the answer is **a**, then how can I set `local_item_size` **wisely** so as use as much resource as possible (without having work groups that are too large)?

If the answer is **b**, then I'm confused (I thought OpenCL has some magic to split the work items up automatically)! Should I re-build the kernel and run it a number of times, changing the input accordingly? If that's the best approach, then how do I choose the number of times to re-build the kernel **wisely**?

Thanks for reading, I look forward to figuring this out!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Part 1 of the question:**

You should select the local work size based on the following information obtained with the `clGetKernelWorkGroupInfo()` function:

- CL_KERNEL_WORK_GROUP_SIZE: Maximum local size that can be used to execute a kernel on a specific device.
- CL_KERNEL_PREFERRED_WORK_GROUP_SIZE_MULTIPLE: Get the preferred multiple for the local size. This is a performance hint, and is probably the most important piece of information to optimize your local work sizes.

You can instead query your device for some of this information using the `clGetDeviceInfo()` function:

- CL_DEVICE_MAX_WORK_ITEM_SIZES: Maximum number of work-items that can be specified in each dimension of the work-group (this is only required if you launch multidimensional kernels, which doesn't seem to be the case).
- CL_DEVICE_MAX_WORK_GROUP_SIZE: Maximum number of work-items in a work-group.

In other words, you can't have local sizes larger than CL_KERNEL_WORK_GROUP_SIZE or CL_DEVICE_MAX_WORK_GROUP_SIZE, and the local size should be a multiple of CL_KERNEL_PREFERRED_WORK_GROUP_SIZE_MULTIPLE. You should use this information to determine your local size, regardless of having very large number of problems.

**Part 2 of the question:**

Mainly this depends on the number of work-groups (i.e. global size divided by local size). Work groups are usually executed on GPU compute units (a.k.a. streaming multiprocessor or SIMD core), so if your GPU has enough compute units, it will schedule your work-groups in an approximately simultaneous fashion, if not, it may process some work-groups at each time.

However, the most important aspect in terms of performance is in fact the local size, which determines how fast can a compute unit process a complete work-group. Each compute unit will have a number of processing elements (a.k.a shader units, CUDA cores  or SIMD lanes), which usually determine how many work-items in a work-group you can execute simultaneously. This is known as the warp size (NVidia) or wavefront (AMD), and is the value returned by the CL_KERNEL_PREFERRED_WORK_GROUP_SIZE_MULTIPLE. If your local size is a multiple of this value, your GPU will be able to optimally schedule work-items within a compute unit, and process work-groups as quickly as possible.

Note that this is a simplified explanation, but if you use the CL_KERNEL_PREFERRED_WORK_GROUP_SIZE_MULTIPLE hint, you'll most likely get well optimized computations.

Comment: Ah, I understand now! I new that you could query some information from the device, but I didn't realize it was so extensive. Would the information given by queires such as `CL_DEVICE_MAX_WORK_ITEM_SIZES` be set by the driver itself, or does OpenCL have some magic to figure this out? 

This was a really clear answer, thanks a lot!

Comment: @YoruNoHau, you could say that the information provided by these queries is returned by the driver. OpenCL is just an open standard (specified in https://www.khronos.org/opencl/), there is no definitive OpenCL implementation. What you have is OpenCL implementations provided by several vendors of GPUs, CPUs, FPGAs and other processors, all of which must conform to the open standard. You are using the OpenCL implementation bundled with your GPU's driver, which knows how to query the hardware when you request specific information such as CL_DEVICE_MAX_WORK_ITEM_SIZES.

Comment: You can install additional OpenCL implementations, and chose which one to use at run time. Intel and AMD provide implementations for their CPUs and GPUs. There are several open source implementations such as [POCL](http://portablecl.org/) or [FreeOCL](https://code.google.com/p/freeocl/), and you can even write one yourself following the spec and the [public headers](https://www.khronos.org/registry/cl/).For example I wrote a [partially mocked OpenCL implementation](https://github.com/FakenMC/cf4ocl/tree/master/src/tests/ocl_stub) to test my [cf4ocl](https://github.com/FakenMC/cf4ocl) library.

Comment: I see now! I suppose it's obvious in retrospect, but until now I had viewed OpenCL as some kind of API developed by khronos, rather than simply a specification to be implemented by hardware developers.

I think I will check out some of the open source implementations for a learning experience. Hey, thanks again!